# Using seasonality in a model

Tags: time-series, seasonality

Suppose you are modeling sales of a prepackaged good and suppose there are seasonal periods in the time series. Also suppose that the brand of the prepackaged good you are modeling comprises the majority of the category(90%) volume. How do you determine what the best seasonality variable to use is? I have heard that if the brand you are modeling comprises the majority of category volume, then you should use a fourier series to model seasonality and if otherwise, create a seasonality index based on the category trend. Any insights into why this should be the case?

Comment: What is a "seasonality variable"? A "seasonality index"?

Comment: I find this an interesting question too, but I suspect it'd fit better on an economics or econometrics site.

Comment: Not clarified, so voting to close.